# Receive 'CSRF Token has been associated to this client' in spring cloud gateway webapp

Tags: spring, security, cloud, gateway

I'm writing a spring cloud gateway webapp (spring boot 2).
Here is my security config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthEntryPoint authEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(authService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class).build();
        http.headers().cacheControl();
    }
}
```

And here is my routes inside yml:

```
      routes:
        - id: auth-service
          uri: http://localhost:8183/
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/auth-service/**
        - id: product-service
          uri: http://localhost:8181/
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/product-service/**
        - id: order-service
          uri: http://localhost:8182/
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/order-service/**
```

When I execute this post:
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/login' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data '{
"username": "sample",
"password": "sample"
}'

I receive this error:
HTTP ERROR 403  - CSRF Token has been associated to this client
Does anyone know why?

Thanx